# Unable to use peer command in docker dev mode in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to test a custom Node JS Chaincode for hyperledger. From the documentation and videos, I understood that I need to use Docker dev mode so that I can access my dev environment out of the box.

I tried to start a basic network using the fabric-samples/basic-network/ folder as suggested by this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzwR0dwzXNs.

After I start the network, I am unable to use the peer command through the command line. For example, the below command is not working

CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/correctPath/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp peer0.org1.example.com peer channel list

I suspect that I am unable to avoid my peer from using TLS. How do I overcome this? Or is there some other issue?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I am seeing this:


peer: command not found

Comment: Seems like the peer executable is not in your PATH.

Comment: How do I add that ?

Comment: which OS are you using?  And I assume you followed the directions for downloading and installing the Fabric images?

Comment: I am using MAC OS. I did follow the instructions and I installed the fabric images. Can you please point out which fabric image I could be missing?

Comment: Cool ... makes it easier if you used the install instructions.  The peer executable should be in the `bin` folder of the `fabric-samples` directory.  For example, on my Mac it's at `/Users/gsingh/Projects/gerrit-hl/fabric-samples/bin`.  So you just need to add that to your path.  Again in my case it would be `export PATH=/Users/gsingh/Projects/gerrit-hl/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 0):

move to

cd ~

```
nano .bash_profile
```

then add

```
export PATH=[download path here]/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH
```

then

source .bash_profile

```
peer version
```